# ctrl+cmd+f full screen mode support shortcut for Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos

Noticed since 10.10, Apple has involved a new built-in shortcut for full screen mode, now I should make it happen on my app, I thought it would be easy, but I can't find some useful links on web. Can someone give me some tips?